# Why is Scala unable to infer the type of an anonymous function when there is method overloading and only one method takes a function?

Tags: scala, type-inference, overloading

Given the following pair of overloaded functions:

```
def onAction_=(implicit aeh: jfxe.EventHandler[jfxe.ActionEvent]) {
  onAction() = aeh
}
def onAction_=(handler: ActionEvent => Unit): Unit = {
  onAction() = new jfxe.EventHandler[jfxe.ActionEvent] {
    override def handle(event: jfxe.ActionEvent): Unit = handler(event)
  }
}
```

When trying to use the assignment method as such

```
onAction = { ae => doSomething() }
```

Scala complains about a missing type parameter for `ae`. Why is Scala unable to infer the type of `ae` since only one of the overloads takes a function type, and thus there is no confusion about which method to call.

Does the Scala compiler simply give up on trying to infer types when it sees an overloaded function?

P.S. As an interesting aside, the IntelliJ Scala plugin is able to resolve the type of `ae` to be that of `ActionEvent`. I'm amused at the plugin being able to do something the compiler cannot, or does not.

Comment: No, it's definitely possible to have the input type of the function inferred in a situation like this. Can you minimize the issue to a self-contained example with no dependencies and no extraneous stuff (syntactic `_=` sugar, implicits, etc.)?

Comment: I was trying to minimise the issue to a self contained example, and noticed that, well, it worked when I removed all my imports. Apparently there was an implicit conversion of similar function signature, and the compiler basically didn't know which to choose. I guess this question can be considered as a false alarm of sorts. Should I just give an answer with how I resolved it, at least as a cautionary tale?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing a getter/accessor. You can't have a setter without a getter. Here is a complete example which compiles:

```
import javafx.{ event => jfxe }

class Foo {
  private var _onAction: jfxe.EventHandler[jfxe.ActionEvent] = _

  def onAction = _onAction // the getter is necessary!

  def onAction_=(implicit aeh: jfxe.EventHandler[jfxe.ActionEvent]) {
    _onAction = aeh
  }
  def onAction_=(handler: jfxe.ActionEvent => Unit): Unit = {
    _onAction = new jfxe.EventHandler[jfxe.ActionEvent] {
      override def handle(event: jfxe.ActionEvent): Unit = handler(event)
    }
  }
}

object Driver extends App {
  val f = new Foo
  f.onAction = { ae => doSomething() }

  def doSomething(): Unit = ???
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer, and I hope it turns out to be helpful to someone, but the lack of a getter really isn't the issue in my question, and I did note that the problem stemmed from a missing type parameter, rather than some other issue. On a related note, if you did lack a getter, the compiler would complain of a reassignment to val or something similar. I wish it'd say something like missing getter, but that could be an impossible task.

Comment: I inferred what I could about the code you did not include. I get the same error you described if I remove the getter and rename the var to `onAction`. Perhaps you can start with the code I posted and add back your functionality until you find the issue.